# Terraform variables.tf from one module not visible by other module

Tags: terraform

I'm trying to implement [Sharing Common Variables](https://microsoft.github.io/code-with-engineering-playbook/continuous-delivery/recipes/terraform/share-common-variables-naming-conventions/)

Directory structure:

```
common/
  outputs.tf
  terraform.tfvars
  variables.tf
tut/
  main.tf
  outputs.tf
main.tf
```

I want to share `common/variables.tf` between other modules (`tut` here but also others if they come later)

and stuck with error after run:

```
cd tut
terraform plan
```

```
Error: Reference to undeclared input variable
│ 
│   on main.tf line 13, in module "common":
│   13:   gcp_project = var.gcp_project
│ 
│ An input variable with the name "gcp_project" has not been declared. This variable can be declared with a variable "gcp_project" {} block.
```

tut/main.tf has this

```
terraform {
  required_version = ">= 0.12"
  required_providers {
    google = {
       version = ">=5"
    }
  }  
}

module "common" {
  source = "../common"

  gcp_project = var.gcp_project
  .....
}


provider "google" {
  project     = module.common.gcp_project
  credentials = file(module.common.gcp_auth_file)
  region      = module.common.gcp_region
}

......
}
```

I have definition of variable `gcp_project` in `common/variables.tf` file. But for some reason `tut/main.tf` does not see it. When I cp `variables.tf` to tut directory, it works. But that is not the solution of course, because the goal is to share common variables for the whole project. And that is the purpose of `common` module.

After a few hours I have no idea what I'm missing here.

Comment: each module must have own variables: https://microsoft.github.io/code-with-engineering-playbook/continuous-delivery/recipes/terraform/share-common-variables-naming-conventions/#common-terraform-module

Comment: Correct @HelderSepulveda

Comment: that article is very misleading, it says: `In Terraform, every input variable must be defined at the configuration (or module) level, using the variable block.` then on the next paragraph: `One way to bypass this limitations is to introduce a "common" module` but if you look closely at what is doing that is not "sharing" variables in the sense that you don't need the variable block again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that common module means that you will have **common resources** included if you load common module from another modules, not specific parts of that module.

It looks like you want exactly have `variables.tf` file shared.

In Terraform you can't just "include" common files. It required to have each file that need defined per module.

Shortcut solution can be next:

```
# inside tut directory
ln -s ../common/variables.tf variables.tf
```

This will create symbolic link to `variables.tf` in common module.

Comment: I choose this as the closest solution but still not perfect, but this is effect of the terraform way of working.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your help.
To summarize

- There is no terraform way to share variables between modules.
- Workaround is to use links like @SerhiiH suggested. But this also had some side effects later (like git repo, Windows machines maybe).
- The article mentioned above from MS site is somewhat misleading. When you follow it you will be surprised the way it defines 'sharing'.